# Error from open image action in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, actions

I am using QGIS 3.6.

By clicking on a polygon I want that an image associated to this polygon appears (as a pop-up window e.g.). The path for the pics are stored in the attribute table (string field).

Creating a generic action:
[image: action window]

with the following action text:

`open [%image%]` or `open [%"image"%]`

doesn´t function showing the error:

[image: error message]

With these [instructions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html) the action still doesn´t function.

What I´m doing wrong?

UPDATE: the appropriate images are store locally (no websites, no URL links). The images should appear locally and not as a website pop up in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

This method works for websites or images (will show in a QGIS 3 Window/Browser)

You will need to point your field **url** in this case with some Python.

In this case, using the **url** field (and linking an action)

[image: example1]

Then using the Python code

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("[%url%]"))
web.show()
```

[image: example2]

then click on the action **"open web"**

creates a new window QGIS 3 to the web URL (or image)

[image: example3]

this can be your localhost (depending on if using mac/windows/unix)

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. I just updated my question. The action should be able to display locally stored images and not websites (relative paths in the appropriate attribute table field and not url links).

Comment: QGIS can pull up the images from your local pc and display them.

Comment: Yeah, without doubt :) I suggest a python code similar to the url links is necessary. Do you have any idea how the python code should look like? Unfortunately I´m not a python expert so I don´t know the exact variables and parameters. Txh in advance.